# Java How to send class Type in parameter

Tags: java

I would like to create a method that would accept any class type and send it to another method. and then returns object: Example:

```
private Object getObjectFromData(Object object, String data) {
    Object o = mapper.readValue(data,Object.class);
    return o;
}
```

Well this works. And does exactly what I want. But to call this function I have to initialize one empty project: like below:

```
final Task t = new Task();
Task task = (Task)getObjectFromData(t,data);
```

Is it possible to somehow skip the line :

```
final Task t = new Task();
```

? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Ferrybig I am sorry that I didn't make my problem clear to you. But I wasnt sure what I wanted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass it the `Class` instance:

```
private Object getObjectFromData(Class clazz, String data) {
    Object o = mapper.readValue(data,clazz);
    return o;
}
```

and call it as follows:

```
Task task = (Task) getObjectFromData(Task.class, data);
```

You should also make the method generic (don't use the raw type `Class` but use `Class<T>` instead), which removes the need to cast:

```
private <T> T getObjectFromData(Class<T> clazz, String data) {
```

and call it as follows:

```
Task task = getObjectFromData(Task.class, data);
```

Comment: You don't need the `(Task)` cast, which is the point of the question ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Indeed because the `Class` should not ideally be used as a raw type.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. :) I am new to those generic <T> stuff. But I kinda like them. Thank you once again :)